# How to add today filter in Sale order search view

Tags: odoo

I have tried.

```
<filter string="Today" doamin="['date_order','=',datetime.now()]"/>
```

But,It gives an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @ket, is possible to create such a filter from the UI in Developer mode? I don't have access to the files of my server.

Answer (score 4):

Domain is supposed to be a list of tuples. You created a list, but forgot about a tuple. Additionally you made a typo ("doamin"). The code below should execute without errors:

```
<filter string="Today" domain="[('date_order','=',datetime.now())]"/>
```

I don't think however, this is what you want. `date_order` is a `datetime` field. This will only select orders with the current date **and time** (so not all today's orders).

Here is an example of a proper "Today" filter on a `datetime` field (based on `stock.move.search` view in the `stock` module):

```
<filter string="Today" domain="[('date_order','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(0,0,0))), ('date_order','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(23,59,59)))]"/>
```

Basically `date_order` has to be greater or equal to the beginning of the current day (00:00:00), but less or equal to the end of the current day (23:59:59).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the today's records by applying bellow condition in your filter domain. It's simple and short.

```
<filter string="Today Orders" domain="[('date_order', '=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"/>
```

It will return all records with today order date.